# How to organise components of a no framework project?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, data-structures, php-7.2

**SHORT VERION:** Where is the common place to store the controllers for dependencies in PHP?

**LONG VERSION:** I need to create a project at a high quality, coming from a framework background my knowledge on directory structure is a bit rusty and I would like some help.

Current Directory Structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cPKu.png

I use the "controllers" driectory for controllers as callbacks for my routes. Each HTML page I create I assign a controller to its route. I ran into a problem when I had to create a "controller" for a dependencies, for example the Twig template engine. From past experience I've learnt that you shouldn't directly call to the twig library from a created instance, you should create a class that holds an instance and make calls through that class, am I correct?

This brings a new problem, I don't know how to structure this. I'm not sure if their called controllers or not, but where do I place these in my project directory structure? What is the common practice?

Putting them inside the controllers directory seems messy, as that's reserved for page controllers. Coming from a Laravel background, I've never had to do this. So my questions are, 'Is my current directory structure okay?', and 'Where do the "controllers" for dependencies go?' ?

Comment: Try this as an example: https://github.com/teresko/blank (you can run it by executing: `php -S localhost:8000 public/built-in.php`) .... I really need to write a readme for that thing, but it probably would end up taking more time that coding it in the first place :(

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at this, FYI it would be much nicer with a README ;), but take that as you wish.

Comment: It's something I wrote in an hour for a completely unrelated conversation in the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) ... readme was not needed at that time, since I was able to "explain on fingers" all the relevant parts.

Comment: A note: you should have a folder ("public" or similar) in the role of the document root inside your project root, where only the index.php and the client-side assets (css, js, images, etc) would reside. Only the content in this folder is accessible fom outside; the access to all other project resources is forbidden.